# How to capture and extract data for analytics

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics

There is a page that lists rewards. Each reward is a Sitecore item and is clickable. Reward details would be displayed in a popup with in the page.

User can apply for a reward by clicking on Apply button in popup or can simply close that popup. We want to capture details like:

1. How many rewards did a user just view.
2. How many rewards did a user apply for.
3. How many rewards were just viewed by people.
4. How many rewards were applied by people.

I am new to the analytics area and looking for some help here.
Will assigning individual goals (view reward & apply reward) for each reward item be the right approach.  (Like trigger goal on opening popup & trigeering for apply click.)

If yes, what would be the best way to extract the data for further analytics.
Is it querying mongodb or can we write any sql queries in reporting db.

Do we have any out of the box API available to extract this data?

using Sitecore 8.2

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a very broad question. You might have more success engaging in a conversation on Sitecore Community, or checking in on the #digital-strategy channel on Sitecore Slack.

Answer (score 1):

Reporting database is basically the aggregated data from the collection database [mongo DB]. Sitecore predefined reports uses data from the Reporting Database, looks like you are just expecting the visits based on Goal so you can get it from Reporting DB [unless you have a very specific requirement to access mongo DB].

You can extract the data by writing your own query [refer the existing queries here /sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Report Queries] and also you can create a custom report to show them in Sitecore CMS. I don't find a link to create your own report in 8.2 but similar to 9.0 https://doc.sitecore.com/users/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/creating-a-custom-experience-analytics-report.html

I don't think that there is an API to extract the historical data, so querying would be an easiest way.